# "Append to array variable" action performs badly

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic App that uses an Array Variable as a buffer to hold messages. Each message is just over 2K bytes.

In the Portal if I navigate to the Run History, select a run, and then look at the Run Details I see this:

[image]

That's 27s to add 100 2K messages to an array.

This seems a very long time for what I would have thought should be a quick Action.

Is this to be expected?

What alternative approach should I take (perhaps I would be better off using Table Storage)?

**Update 2018-09-28**
I tried using Table Storage instead of an Array Variable but the performance was about the same.